# Inscape Version of Corel Draw's Clone Tool

Tags: inkscape, corel-draw

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this: [Corel Draw Clone Tool YouTube Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGeXAS4zS7A)
 in Inkscape? I'm very familiar with Corel Draw and Adobe Creative Suite, but at my new job they are cheap and I'm stuck with Inkscape.

I've been trying to figure it out for a while now and can't find any documentation on a tool similar to this.

Comment: I realized that this a pretty irrelevant question. Inkscape is vectors and I want to do raster editing. Duh. Went with [GimpShop](http://www.gimpshop.com/) and it works great. Even found a tutorial on how to do exactly what I want: [GIMP Clone Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-clone.html)

Answer (score 4):

To create a *"clone"* of an object, i.e. an object linked to the original in Inkscape:

1. Select the object
2. Clone the object <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (or menu *Edit - Clone - Create clone*)

Choose to *Create Tiled Clones...* for any number of tiled clones.

*Additional note:* The clone tool from Inkscape is capable to also clone embedded bitmap images.

[image]
(Example of tiled clones with lineart and embbedded bitmaps)