# How to clone objects in Inkscape so that ctrl-D will show the original object?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am editing a game board for a word game, based on a "CC BY SA"-licensed [SVG file by Denelson83](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg):

[image: Inkscape screenshot]

When I click at a colored square and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> I can see the original colored square - as you can see at the above screenshot.

Editing that original object will change all its copies at the game board, which is very comfortable.

However, when I copy the original object with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then paste it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, that connection is gone. I can't press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> anymore and jump to the original object.

**My question is:** How to clone that colored squares and keep the connection?

Comment: this may help you: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21888/inscape-version-of-corel-draws-clone-tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I have [found the answer](http://www.microugly.com/inkscape-quickguide/#clone-objects): you can clone objects with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and the cloned object will be placed above the original one.

Also, it is possible to relink the clones with [`Edit -> Clones -> Relink to Copied`](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clones.html)