# How can I reuse an embedded raster image multiple times in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, raster, embed

I have an svg image made in Inkscape with about five raster images embedded in it. Each of these images is used many times (up to 72). Each of these images is small (<1MB), but judging from the file size (>80MB), the images are not reused but embedded over and over again. 
Can Inkscape somehow minimize it and have each unique raster embedded only once?

Comment: For cloning also see: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21888/inscape-version-of-corel-draws-clone-tool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Embed the original image once and for each other instance of that image use a clone *(Edit → Clone → Create Clone)* and not a duplicate of the original image.

Comment: Can this be done after the image has been copy-pasted by some optimization procedure?

Comment: How does an optimisation procedure copy-paste something?

Comment: The image has been copy-pasted many times within the image. The question was, whether there is some procedure in Inkscape that would look for identical bitmaps and make them to clones instead of repeated instances.

Comment: I am not aware of something. Perhaps you can take a look at the XML source and write a small script that does the job. Alternatively you can manually replace them using *Paste Size* and aligning.